# When I export an MySQL database, will it delete everything on the database after it's exported?

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin, export

I want to literally 'copy' a database to an other server using PHPMyAdmin. But the old database can not be effected. So I figured that I had to export it on the old server and import it on the new one. But when I export the old database, will it directly delete all the exported data? As you have probably noticed, I'm not that good at English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in one word, No it won't be deleted. Not as PHPMyAdmin is configured by default at least.

Comment: i exported my database and it deleted